# How to convert language of data which retrive from api in react-native

Tags: react-native, language-translation

I have used the react-native-i18n which convert the app language either mobile langage or multiselect langauge.
But how to convert data which fetched from api which language is English.
This is code which convert constant data. but in my app maximum data have come from api, and i want to convert that data as i change the constant data. Is there any mathod or library which direct translate all data in selected language.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';

I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.translations = {
  'en': require('./translations/en'),
  'fr': require('./translations/fr'),
  'fr-CA': require('./translations/fr-CA'),
  'es': require('./translations/es'),
};

const language = [
      {lang: "English", code: "en"},
      {lang: "French", code: "fr"},
      {lang: "French Canada", code: "fr-CA"},
      {lang: "Spanish", code: "es"},
    ]

export default class extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      languages: [],
      value: false,
      langValue: "en",
      select: "Select Language",
    }
    this.onLanguage=this.onLanguage.bind(this);
  }

  onSelectLanguage() {
    return(
      language.map((data, i)=>{
        return (
          <View key={i} style={styles.dropDownView}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.onSelectedLang(data)}>
              <Text style={styles.dropDownText}>{data.lang}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )
      })
    )
  }

  onSelectedLang(text) {
    this.setState({
      value: false,
      select: text.lang,
    }),
    I18n.locale = text.code;
  }
  onLanguage() {
    this.setState({
      value: true,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.mainTitle}>React-native langauge translation</Text>
        <View style={styles.subContainer}>
          <View style={styles.block}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Langauge Translation</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{I18n.t('hello world')}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{I18n.t('thank you')}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{I18n.t('Bye')}</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onLanguage}>
              <View style={styles.buttonView}>
                <Text style={styles.buttontext}>{this.state.select}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
            {(this.state.value) ? this.onSelectLanguage() : null}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While asking the question you need add code snippet that helps others to understand what have you done so far.

Comment: just landed here because of the i18next tag - react-native-i18n is not build on i18next -> that would be react-i18next ;)...